# getting text from EditText in android

Tags: android, search, android-edittext

I have written this code for searching a text file for a string. The problem is, it says that the string is not found even if it is present. Process is to receive the text from the `EditText` and then start the searching process. But it shows that string is found every time.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button;
    final EditText obedittext;

    button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    obedittext =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                boolean textfound;
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    textfound = searchtext(obedittext.getText().toString());
                    if(textfound)
                        maketoast(obedittext.getText().toString());
                    else
                        maketoast("Unsuccessfull");
                }
    });

}

protected boolean searchtext(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("mneumo.txt")));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(sCurrentLine.equals(string)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        br.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        finally{

        }
    return false;
}


private void maketoast(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, string , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

So when i tried to give the string inside the code itself instead of getting it from the `edittext`,it works fine. Like this,
`string = "SPINAL ANESTHESIA AGENTS";`

The sample text file is,

```
SPINAL ANESTHESIA AGENTS
XYLOCAINE: WHERE NOT TO USE WITH EPINEPHRINE
GENERAL ANAESTHESIA: EQUIPMENT CHECK PRIOR TO INDUCING
```

So how can i rectify this problem? Can anyone say why i am getting this problem?
Should i any other method to compare the strings?

The text file is correctly placed in the assets folder. And i accessed it using the assetmanager. And i am a total newbie to android development.

Comment: Change if(sCurrentLine.equals(string)) { to if(string.contains(sCurrentLine)){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your editText contain some white space already, To get text from your editText try this:

```
obedittext.getText().toString().trim();
```

and inside your searchtext() method, replace your if condition with:

```
if(sCurrentLine.equalsIgnoreCase(string))
```